# Is it possible to determine a tab's opener within a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am looking for a way to determine a given tab's opener (parent tab) within a Google Chrome extension.

I've looked at the documention for Tab but there doesn't really seem to be anything that would yield this information. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html

I've tried injecting this content script into pages (thinking I could pass the value to my background page):

```
alert(window.opener);
```

.. but it just yields null.

The best thing I've come up with so far is to keep track of the currently focused tab, and whenever a new tab is created, just assume that the focused tab is the opener/parent of the new tab. I believe this would *de facto* identify the parent tab correctly most of the time since background tabs rarely (are allowed to) open new pages. However, it seems kludgey and potentially inaccurate at times -- for example, if another extension opened a new tab, this method may misidentify the new tab's opener.

Comment: May I ask what kind of extension are you/were you building? I'm looking for a very simple one that would have this exact functionality very simply: Whenever I am in doubt of 'where I come from' or what opened what, I would like to know the parent of the current tab. Can your extension by any chance answer that question for me? Or even if not, maybe you know of a similar extension?

Comment: Has anyone built such an extension and released it or does mind sharing access?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** it is now possible to reliably determine a tab's opener tab within a Chrome extension natively using the newly added webNavigation API, and specifically by hooking the onCreatedNavigationTarget event.

https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webNavigation.html

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has added an experimental extension API which can accomplish this -- specifically webNavigation.onBeforeRetarget. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webNavigation.html

However since this is still experimental (not usable in Chrome stable versions or releasable on the Chrome Web Store) I have ended up using another approach.

Basically:

In content_script.js:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({
    request: {
        op: "pageLoadStarted", 
        url: document.location.href, 
        referrer: document.referrer
    }
});
```

In background.html:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
    console.log('onRequest: ' + JSON.stringify(request)); 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sender)); 
  });
```

This approach allows me to obtain the **referrer** of a tab, which I can then correlate with an existing tab's url. This isn't always a one-to-one mapping, so I do some additional magic such as preferring the currently selected tab as the opener if its url matches the new tab's referrer.

This really is just a hack to approximate the functionality that would be provided more simply and accurately by webNavigation.onBeforeRetarget or window.opener.

Answer (score 1):

Further investigation has revealed that onCreatedNavigationTarget() does not *always* fire when you think it would to indicate an opener-opened relationship.

An additional hint can sometimes be found in the Tab object returned by chrome.tabs.onCreated/onUpdated in the .openerTabId parameter.

A comprehensive solution will probably have to rely on multiple of the methods described in these answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
port.onMessage.addListener(
     function(msg) {
         var tabid = port.sender.tab.openerTabId;
         console.log("Received message from tab that was opened by tab id : " + tabid);
         // reliably shows the tab id of the tab that opened
         // the tab sending the message
     });
```