# chrome content script: window.postMessage() "message" event does not contain the "source" property

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm building a chrome extension that adds a content script to a site (let's call it the host). the content script creates an iframe in the host which leads to my domain (cross domain).

I'm able to send messages from the iframe to the host via parent.postMessage(). however, the 'message' event received does not contain a 'source' property which blocks me from communicating messages back to the child.

**UPDATE**
I'm looking for a client side solution or an explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: This definitely sound like a bug. I don't see why `source` would be omitted just because the source iframe was injected via content script. I did a quick test, and I got it work correctly when the injected source iframe was a `chrome-extension://` page, rather than an `http://` page. (I have not yet tested with an `http://` page.)

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure, we're talking about the 'source' property, right? The 'origin' is there and it's valid.

Comment: Yeah, both `source` and `origin` were present, and I successfully used `source.postMessage` to reply back to the iframe.

Comment: When I tried to `console.log(e.source)`, I got a error message (but not an execution-halting exception), because `console.log` apparently inquires about `source`'s properties in a way that violates some browser security policy, but `source.postMessage` worked fine.

Comment: Is that confirmed for an "http://" page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an issue with the sandboxed `window` object available in the extension.

A quick workaround is to inject the javascript code directly to the DOM via a `src` element instead of  running it from the extension. This way you're dealing with the regular window objects.

You can see an example in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622219/can-chrome-extension-content-scripts-access-window-opener)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do it the difficult way.

When doing the iframe, send a unique install id in the url.

e.g.
http://www.trackingdomain.tld/trackingscript.php?uid=38736238

then have your script pull a JSON script reply every 1000ms from your domain with the same uid to get the message that is returned.

You could also use the json to send messages.

But this solution would mean you'd be forced to use server side scripting.

Comment: Thanks Michael, This message should create a real time UI reaction so server side solutions are my last resort. Is this known behaviour?

Comment: Postmessage behaviour is flaky at best. The main problem is is that every browser maker has different ideas about it when it should and should not work, and behaviour differs with every version of the software. If you need realtime behaviour analysis just load a javascript file of your script into every webbpage. To be on the safe side host it on a https secure server to avoid security conflict warnings. Or simply inject your javascript into every document that loads. That way you can make sure the behaviour is real time. And eventual status message/statistics can be sent via ajax to your site