# Chrome extension - content script - to get innerText of current tab - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get the `innerText` of the current opened tab in a chrome extension.

Here's my **manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "meow",
  "description": "meow-meow-meow",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon2.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "js": ["contentscript.js"]
   }
  ],

  "permissions": [
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*",
  "contextMenus",
  "tabs"
  ]

}
```

Here's my **contentscript.js**:

```
function getText(){
return document.body.innerText
}

console.log(getText());
```

But it isn't logging anything on the console!
What am I missing?

**EDIT**: Is there a better way to get the HTML content from the current tab?

**UPDATED EDIT**:

**This runs fine on my friend's chrome, but not on mine, both Chrome versions are 26.**

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622219/can-chrome-extension-content-scripts-access-window-opener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Works fine on my browser

Reload the extension.

if it still does not work,
sign out of Google Chrome and sign in again.

Comment: Thanks reloading the extension and re-starting chrome worked. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

it works in my chrome browser.

open the url `chrome://extensions/`, load the plugin directory.
and make sure it load correctly， and mark it enable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it works in my friend's browser too, but not on mine!!! 

Do you happen to know why?