# Application to distribute HTML contents securely

Tags: security, encryption, https

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I need to develop a security application (for Android and Windows in the first place) that does the following:

1. Asks for user authentication
2. Connects to a server through HTTPS, authenticates the user
3. Retrieves HTML contents from the server
4. Displays the contents
5. Stores the contents in a way that only the app is able to read it and display it (after user authentication at the app level), and also it is very hard to anyone with access to the device (it could be a computer, smartphone or tablet) to obtain the original contents without the user's password. Probably some encryption will be needed.

My question is whether you know of some implementation of anything like this, specially, the 5th step is the crux point. Something open source will be the best, but also any proprietary implementation may give me a starting inspiration.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: This is very broad, likely too broad for Stack Overflow. For points 1-4, might get away with a standard web application that runs in a browser, through https. If you do that, for point 5, you'll have to decide whether browser local storage is secure enough. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280390/can-local-storage-ever-be-considered-secure If you don't want to go the web app route, you'd have to build an application - in which case I'd recommend you define what platforms you can use, and then look for secure storage options around those platforms

Comment: @Pekka웃 added platform, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, but this is still not likely to work as a question I'm afraid. It's just too broad. You need to break up the task, research the parts (like how to securely store data in an Android app) and ask new specific questions if you get stuck.