# How to securely store localstorage in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, security, local-storage

Is there any way to store localstorage securely, like encrypting and decrypting the localstorage data. I don't want other users to manipulate the localstorage data. 
If that is not possible with localstorage, what are the other ways to store data at client side?

I have seen websql, but that is also get manipulated easily by writing queries in console.

**Note**: Can you please provide the solution for Angular 2+ !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can local storage ever be considered secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280390/can-local-storage-ever-be-considered-secure)

Comment: @TomaszKula nice thread linked, thx for sharing.

Comment: @TomaszKula, so you said this question is duplicate. I didn't get any answer from your shared link. Can you tell me how to secure the localstorage. If you don't know leave it. no problem.

Comment: @JSSA It does provide an answer, please read it properly.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Yeah, i read the answer. from that answer what I understood is that, they are saying "Don't use Javascript crypto" and "WebCrypto API, but that is not here yet". I didn't get the answer like "Use this libraray or this method to secure localstorage". That is what I want.

Comment: In that case I do not understand why is the answer you got below the one which helped you. It just repeats what he linked duplicate question said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to the other answer, you **can** securely store any value in the client, where by "securely" I mean the value is not known to the client and/or cannot be modified. The storage mechanism can be localStorage, websql or whatever else. The catch is that Javascript code will not be able to read and/or modify such a value either, because obviously Javascript *is* the client from what you want to protect such data.

If you have a server-side secret (a key), you can use that to encrypt (for confidentiality) and/or sign (for integrity) any data sent to the client. This is how frameworks like Rails handle sessions by default without server-side persistance and still relatively securely.

Note that simply encrypting a cookie on the server will not necessarily authenticate its contents (see authenticated encryption), and also such a cookie would be vulnerable to replay attacks, against which you can use a timestamp or a nonce. You have to care about forward secrecy if you need it. So in short you have to take care of stuff yourself, which is not straightforward, but not impossible either.

If you only sign data but not encrypt it, Javascript may have access to it, but still won't be able to modify.

Answer (score 4):

**No there isn't any way to store data in client side which client won't be able to manipulate.**

In angular, you can save data in services but that will be cleared if user refreshes the browser.

Comment: Thanks dude, for your answer

Comment: welcome. Please select this as answer if you're satisfied.

Comment: @KAMRULHASANSHAHED localstorage data can be accessible until you close the browser. User's refresh won't affect the localstorage.

Comment: @SuvethanNantha I said, Data saved in angular service is cleared after the browser refreshes not localstorage data.

Comment: oh then fine, sorry I have mistaken

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but this is simply not true.