# Saved data from lost when page refresh in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a project where I have to save data from losing when the page gets refreshed. How to save data for future use? I don't want to use local storage. 
I have some idea about using AngularJs model but don't know how to use. Can someone help me out from this situtation.

Comment: What's the idea you have about using angularJS model? Because the only two ways I know you can achieve this is by storing it in a remote database and retrieving on page refresh or using localStorage/sessionStorage

Comment: cookies or databases

Comment: But anyone can see the data present in Session, localStorage or cookies, how to hide those data

Comment: Encode your data so that it is gibberish for the user - to completely hide it, you'd have to save it on server side

Comment: Which encryption technique I have to use?

Comment: You cannot use an AngularJS model/service nor anything else, because when the page is reloaded, the application is reloaded as well, so it loses everything it stores. As other suggested, you should use local storage, cookies or a database. If you're concerned about local storage's security issues take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280390/can-local-storage-ever-be-considered-secure