# How can I using local storage to store login information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, storage

My html code like this :

```
<li id="login" class="hide-on-med-and-down">
    <a class="dark-text" style="padding-right:0 !important" href="#">Login</a>
</li>
<li id="user-login">
    <a class="white-txt dropdown-button" href="#" data-activates="user-dropdown">
        <span id="current-lang" data-code="">085132112345</span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul id="user-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <li class=""><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

My javascript code like this :

```
var x = document.getElementById("login");
var y = document.getElementById("user-login");
if (localStorage.getItem("loginChelseaLocalStorage") === null) {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
}
else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "block";
}
```

If the user login, it will store on local storage like this :

```
localStorage.setItem("loginChelseaLocalStorage", true);
```

If the user logout, it will remove local storage like this :

```
localStorage.removeItem("loginChelseaLocalStorage");
```

Is the use of local storage to store login information as above is correct and good?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280390/can-local-storage-ever-be-considered-secure)

Comment: Localstorage can store only `string`s.

Comment: @yqlim So using local storage is not secure?

Comment: @connexo Okay.  How do I make a good and safe name and value of local storage?

Comment: @connexo I know local storage, session storage, cookies. Which is a good and safe choice?

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage store string data so you should use JSON.stringify(true)  and to get the item from local storage you can use JSON.parse(getItem("loginChelseaLocalStorage"))
review the use of Localstorage  here
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: Okay. But how do I make a good and safe name and value of local storage?

Comment: check that it will help you https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Comment: I know local storage, session storage, cookies. Which is a good and safe choice?