# Is it safe to store user information as a crypted jwt in localstorage?

Tags: cookies, jwt, local-storage

I know storing user information in localstorage is unsafe because anyone could access them. However, what if these informations are stored as a crypted jwt (`gCS4$dh+ze%vb!fh` instead of `{name:"joe", age: 45}` for example)? Should I use http-cookie no matter what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can local storage ever be considered secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280390/can-local-storage-ever-be-considered-secure)

Comment: No. I'm not using node crypto module, but jwt. The client needs a secret jwt key to decypher the user information.