# How can I check which tab opened a (popup) window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

### The problem

I've had this issue for months now, but the concept is pretty straightforward: I want to block some Malicious Site™ from programmatically opening tabs or popup windows.

With the [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs), I can listen with [`onCreated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated) when a new tab is created, and **I can easily check who (i.e. which tab) opened that particular tab accessing the `openerTabId` property of the [`Tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) object** passed to the callback function.

Now, **I would like to do the exact same thing when a new window is created**: I would like to know which tab opened the window (if any, because it could have been opened by the user too), check its URL to see if it is the Malicious Site™, and act accordingly (i.e. block the popup). I tried doing it in the exact same way: request the array of tabs in the new window and check their `openerTabId` property, but unfortunately such property is not defined! I searched [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) and Googled for hours, but sadly it **looks like there's no simple way to check who opened a window.**

### A very clumsy solution

Stated the above, the only way I was able to do something even remotely close to what I really want, is the following:

1. Every time a new *window* is *created*, its ID is added to an array called `windowWatchlist`.
2. Every time a *tab* is *updated* (NB: updated, not created), a script is injected inside it to check its `document.referrer`, which *should* contain the URL of the site which opened the tab: if the referrer URL contains the address of the Malicious Site™ I want to block popups from, the window is then closed and removed from the `windowWatchlist`.
3. Every time a *window* is *closed*, if its ID is in the `windowWatchlist`, it gets removed from it.

Here's the code (which runs in my `background.js` script):

```
// Called on chrome.windows.onCreated
function watchPopupWindow(window) {
    windowWatchlist.push(window.id);
    console.log('Added window #' + window.id + ' to watchlist.');
}

// Called on chrome.windows.onRemoved
function unwatchPopupWindow(windowID) {
    var index = windowWatchlist.indexOf(windowID);

    // If the windowID is in the watchlist:
    if (index != -1) {
        // Remove it:
        windowWatchlist.splice(index, 1);
        console.log('Removed window #' + windowID + ' from watchlist.');
    }
}

// Called on chrome.tabs.onUpdated
function blockPopupWindow(tabID, info, tab) {
    // If this tab is in a window which is in the watchlist:
    if (windowWatchlist.indexOf(tab.windowId) != -1 && info.url && info.url != 'about:blank') {
        // Check the referrer of this tab:
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, {code: 'document.referrer;'}, function(ref) {
            // If the referrer is the malicious site to block:
            if (ref && ref[0] && ref[0].indexOf("http://MALICIOUS-SITE.XXX") != -1) {
                // Close the popup window:
                chrome.windows.remove(tab.windowId, function() {
                    console.log('Blocked popup window #' + tab.windowId + '.');

                    if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                });;
            }
        });
    }
}

var windowWatchlist = [];

chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(watchPopupWindow, {windowTypes: ['popup']});
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(unwatchPopupWindow, {windowTypes: ['popup']});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(blockPopupWindow);
```

Now, you may be wondering: **why do you need all this mess only to check a referrer?** Couldn't you just check the tabs contained in the window when the window is opened and check their referrer directly inside the callback of `chrome.window.onCreated`? That's a clever question, and the answer is simple: **the problem is that I cannot check the referrer of the tabs right when they are created, because they almost always need some time to load**, and the referrer isn't loaded until the page starts loading inside the tab. Therefore, I need to check when a tab is *updated*, see if its window is in my watchlist, and then check its referrer. This is why `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` is needed, since it fires its listeners whenever a tab changes state (e.g. `tab.status` changes from `"loading"` to `"complete"`).

### Why this solution doesn't work

The reason why I call this solution "clumsy" and the reason why it doesn't really work should be already clear to anyone with some experience of JavaScript and web developing: **`document.referrer` isn't reliable at all**, and is very often `undefined` or (in case of multiple redirects) not the right one. This makes my script fail about 90% of the times, because it is unable to determine whether the popup window was opened by the Malicious Site™ or not.

Moreover, the Malicious Site™ often opens popups with URL `about:blank` or no URL at all, and only when they are loaded, injects data into them, making them basically impossible to detect, even with `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` which doesn't fire any listener in this situation.

I could decide to block any popup with URL `about:blank` or `undefined`, and this is what I'm doing right now indeed, but is a pretty bad compromise, since that I end up closing popups opened by any site which uses this method, and not only the Malicious Site™ I want to block.

### In conclusion

My question is simple, but I don't know about its solution: **does anyone know any other *more reliable* method which could be used to detect which tab opened a new window?** Nothing comes to my mind, maybe something could be possible using the [`chrome.webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)? I don't really know. For months I've been accepting the fact that a simple solution just wasn't possible, and helplessly waited for an update or something, but I never actually thought about asking here, because the problem looked above the competence of an average Chrome Extension programmer, but hopefully I was wrong.

---

**UPDATE**: The solution to inject a script inside the site and replace the `window.open` function with something else isn't viable: if an `<iframe>` is loaded without a `src` attribute, but with an already written DOM inside the `srcdoc` attribute, Chrome will not execute a content script inside it, even if the call to `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is made with `allFrames: true`, and even if the content script is declared inside the extension's manifest.

Comment: In `windows.onCreated`, you get the list of tabs in the new window; don't they have an `openerTabId` set?

Comment: If it's a site, I usually insert a script element from a content script that runs on `document_start` (i.e. before the site scripts) and spoof `window.open` with a dummy function.

Comment: @Xan forgot to add it to the question, no `openerTabId` is set on the tabs of the new window, sadly.

Comment: @wOxxOm that's a clever solution... I thought about it but I actually didn't try it. Replacing the open method with a closure that checks what's going on could be a valid option. I was trying not to inject anything in the site, but I'll probably have to if I don't find any other solution.

Comment: UPDATE: Sadly it looks like is not possible to use the approach suggested by @wOxxOm, since that iframes that are loaded without a `src="..."` attribute and with a `srcdoc="..."` attribute (containing the DOM) are not affected by `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, even with the option `allFrames: true`. Sites that use this kind of frames can do whatever they want inside the DOM of such frames, and an extension is not able to touch the code or make anything before it gets executed, so if some Malicious Site™ puts a `window.open` inside an `<iframe srcdoc="...">` there's no way to block it.

Comment: Does `"match_about_blank": true` make any difference?

Comment: Also, you need a content script declared in manifest.json with "run_at": "document_start" or declarativeContent with RequestContentScript, not executeScript, which is too late even if you specify runAt: 'document_start'.

Comment: @wOxxOm already tried declaring the content script inside the manifest with `"run_at": "document_start"` without any luck: it gets injected in every frame except frames without `src` which use `srcdoc="..."`. Can you elaborate on `declarativeContent`? Never used this API before.

Comment: declarativeContent won't help if match_about_blank makes no difference.

Comment: One question: do you want the malicious site to be still fully functional and totally unaltered, but just not allowed to open new windows?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Yes, that's *basically* what I would like to accomplish.

Comment: one remark: overwriting `window.open` from a content script is probably not an option in your case as extension scrips are executed in a different context from page scripts and their `window` objects are different.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak no, that is not the reason at all. It is extremely easy to [inject a script inside the context of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704). I already explained why `window.open` is not an option.

Comment: yes you can inject a script, but you cannot change execution context of the page scripts, so running `window.open = () => {}` in your content script will not change `window.open` accessible from page scripts. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment `It's worth noting what happens with JavaScript objects that are shared by the page and the extension - for example, the window.onload event. Each isolated world sees its own version of the object. Assigning to the object affects your independent copy of the object.`

Comment: yes, you are right - sincerely thought it was impossible sorry for confusion.

Have no time to test it myself right now, but one thing you could try is to set `sandbox` attribute on the iframes - especially not to `allow-popups` as described  here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I think this *could* be impossible because of not being able to "catch" the frame and add the attribute, but is definitely something to try, thank you for the link, I'll see if this can help.

Comment: Is the purpose of the extension to block specific sites?

Comment: @guest271314 more or less, yes.

Comment: You can use `PerformanceObserver` at each `window` where extension is loaded to check each request at that `window` [Detect ajax requests from raw HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406906/detect-ajax-requests-from-raw-html), though to achieve requirement for browser itself the user can set one or more `Policies` [chrome Pop-up blocker when to re-check after allowing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282861/chrome-pop-up-blocker-when-to-re-check-after-allowing-page/)

Comment: @guest271314 could you elaborate on this? Maybe with an answer if you think this could work. How can I set policies with an extension? Do I need an app? I don't know much about this, but it looks promising...

Comment: It is probably beyond the scope of an extension to set `Policies`.

Comment: @guest271314 yes, that's probably true, but even without that, I tried setting policies to block popups and I verified they were set in the chrome://policy tab, **but the damn Malicious Site™ managed to open popups anyway**... maybe because they were opened by an event listener? I don't know. I really don't. I'm doomed, this is just hopeless.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Can you reproduce at plnkr https://plnkr.co? Can you include the policies that you tried at Question? Have you read the code used to open the `window`? Did you create a policy for all of the domains used by the code?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't see how plnkr could be useful here, it's just an HTML/JS/CSS fiddler. About the opening of the popups, the problem is that I don't actually know which function calls the `open` method. The site I tested it with is `www.flashx.to`, any page like [this one](https://www.flashx.to/6yduxk1pw6u9.html) opens a bunch of popups when clicking basically anywhere on the page and even injecting the code to remove the `open` function in all the frames it still manages to open them. I added that site to the `PopupsBlockedForUrls` policy, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you list all twenty-six requested JavaScript files at `Policies`?

Comment: @guest271314 no I didn't: that would nullify my efforts to "block" some site, since that I cannot know which files the site is using (and from where), so if the Policy only blocks popups explicitly generated by the url of the frame (and not the top frame)... well... that's an useless policy.

Comment: _"no I didn't: that would nullify my efforts to "block" some site"_ If you are visiting a site which makes numerous requests, including cross domain requests, that is exactly the policy which should be implemented; that is specifically making a policy for each domain where pop ups should be blocked. You cannot expect a policy for a single URL to apply to multiple URLs

Comment: @guest271314 yes, I know that's what the policy is for, you're right, but you also understand that: 1) policies aren't that easy to deal with, not for an extension; 2) I would need to add every single frame URL to the policies every time I open a page of the Malicious Site™, and remove them when I close it, because I don't want to block those URLs on every single site. Policies are what they are, but for the purpose of my extension they are useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the same problem and found the [`webNavigation.onCreatedNavigationTarget`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCreatedNavigationTarget) event that yields the source tab/frame id when a new window is opened.

Solution found from this post: [Is it possible to determine a tab's opener within a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8583044/6518606)

Comment: If this is true you're my savior. I'm gonna check this later today, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Well, turns out this actually works quite well. It's really strange to find this answer only now since this method has been around for **seven years**. I personally don't know how I never came across that answer during my endless searches. The fact that something like this has to be detected through the `webNavigation` API is really strange, but whatever, it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already doing code injection this is what I would do.

Inject code to override `window.open` and have it `window.postMessage` to child window telling them who opened them. Also will need to inject code to listen to the effect of `window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler)` which will decided if they should `window.close()`.

On second though I think I would just override `window.open` and not even open the child windows if you don't want to allow a give site to open windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll test it out.

Comment: Sadly it looks like is not possible to use this approach, since that iframes that are loaded without a src="..." attribute and with a srcdoc="..." attribute (containing the DOM) are not affected by `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, even with the option `allFrames: true`. Sites that use this kind of frames can do whatever they want inside the DOM of such frames, and an extension is not able to touch the code or make anything before it gets executed, so if some Malicious Site™ puts a `window.open` inside an `<iframe srcdoc="...">` there's no way to block it.

Comment: As a sidenote for people who think this is a valid answer and in case it wasn't clear from my comment: it is not. This is just wat @wOxxOm suggested in the comments of my question, just re-formatted and a little bit clearer.